# jquery, .unload() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

Any idea why this code works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'delete_image.php'
});
```

And this one doesn't:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'delete_image.php' 
    });
});
```

In delete_image.php, I just have:

```
unlink('test.jpg');
```

Comment: `$(window).on('unload', function(){`...

Comment: @Spokey so if I'm using version 1.9.1 .unload() won't work???

Comment: @Spokey If it's deprecated but not yet removed, it should still work.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I just tried $(window).on('unload', function(){ but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that depending on what browser you are using, the browser won't wait for the ajax call to complete before the page reload. This seems to work with `async:false;`

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'delete_image.php',
        async:false 
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nNMkw/1/)
- Click `Run` in JsFiddle to unload

Comment: i suspected that the request was not really successful and didn't arrive in the server.

Comment: as of jQuery1.8 async is deprecated it's advice to use the success callback http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, first place it didn't work, then I tried with $(window).on('unload', function(){ and now it seems ok, anyway, thanks a lot!!!